# npm install --global eas-cli failed with Invalid URL

Tags: npm, expo, eas

I failed to run `npm install --global eas-cli`, with error `TypeError [ERR_INVALID_URL]: Invalid URL` as below:

```
➜  ~ node -v
v16.20.2
➜  ~ npm -v
8.19.4
➜  ~ npm config get proxy
null
➜  ~ npm config get https-proxy
null
➜  ~ npm config get registry
https://registry.npmjs.org/
➜  ~ npm config get http-proxy
undefined
```

```
➜  ~ npm install --global eas-cli
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: @expo/prebuild-config@6.2.5
npm WARN Found: expo-modules-autolinking@undefined
npm WARN node_modules/eas-cli/node_modules/expo-modules-autolinking
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer expo-modules-autolinking@">=0.8.1" from @expo/prebuild-config@6.2.5
npm WARN node_modules/eas-cli/node_modules/@expo/prebuild-config
npm WARN   @expo/prebuild-config@"6.2.5" from eas-cli@5.9.1
npm WARN   node_modules/eas-cli
npm ERR! code ERR_INVALID_URL
npm ERR! Invalid URL

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/wliu/.npm/_logs/2023-11-24T19_14_48_930Z-debug-0.log
```

And in the log file:

```
1492 verbose stack TypeError [ERR_INVALID_URL]: Invalid URL
1492 verbose stack     at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:387:5)
1492 verbose stack     at URL.onParseError (node:internal/url:565:9)
1492 verbose stack     at new URL (node:internal/url:641:5)
1492 verbose stack     at getProxyUri (/Users/wliu/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/make-fetch-happen/lib/agent.js:160:53)
1492 verbose stack     at getAgent (/Users/wliu/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/make-fetch-happen/lib/agent.js:21:17)
1492 verbose stack     at remoteFetch (/Users/wliu/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/make-fetch-happen/lib/remote.js:31:17)
1492 verbose stack     at cacheFetch (/Users/wliu/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/make-fetch-happen/lib/cache/index.js:16:28)
1492 verbose stack     at async fetch (/Users/wliu/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/make-fetch-happen/lib/fetch.js:98:7)
1492 verbose stack     at async RegistryFetcher.packument (/Users/wliu/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/pacote/lib/registry.js:92:19)
1492 verbose stack     at async RegistryFetcher.manifest (/Users/wliu/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/pacote/lib/registry.js:124:23)
1493 verbose cwd /Users/wliu/.npm/_logs
1494 verbose Darwin 21.6.0
1495 verbose node v16.20.2
1496 verbose npm  v8.19.4
```

---

[UPDATE]
Changed to node v21, same error:

```
➜  ~ node -v
v21.2.0
➜  ~ npm -v
10.2.3
➜  ~ npm install --global eas-cli
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: @expo/prebuild-config@6.2.5
npm WARN Found: expo-modules-autolinking@undefined
npm WARN node_modules/eas-cli/node_modules/expo-modules-autolinking
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer expo-modules-autolinking@">=0.8.1" from @expo/prebuild-config@6.2.5
npm WARN node_modules/eas-cli/node_modules/@expo/prebuild-config
npm WARN   @expo/prebuild-config@"6.2.5" from eas-cli@5.9.1
npm WARN   node_modules/eas-cli
npm ERR! code ERR_INVALID_URL
npm ERR! Invalid URL

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /Users/wliu/.npm/_logs/2023-11-24T19_21_26_890Z-debug-0.log

*** And here is the log ***

1505 timing idealTree:node_modules/eas-cli/node_modules/rimraf/node_modules/glob Completed in 2ms
1506 silly placeDep node_modules/eas-cli/node_modules/rimraf brace-expansion@1.1.11 OK for: minimatch@3.1.2 want: ^1.1.7
1507 timing idealTree:node_modules/eas-cli/node_modules/rimraf/node_modules/minimatch Completed in 1ms
1508 timing idealTree:node_modules/eas-cli/node_modules/rimraf/node_modules/brace-expansion Completed in 0ms
1509 timing idealTree:node_modules/eas-cli/node_modules/supports-hyperlinks/node_modules/supports-color Completed in 0ms
1510 timing idealTree:node_modules/eas-cli/node_modules/tar/node_modules/mkdirp Completed in 0ms
1511 timing idealTree:node_modules/eas-cli/node_modules/tempy/node_modules/type-fest Completed in 0ms
1512 timing idealTree:node_modules/eas-cli/node_modules/xcode/node_modules/uuid Completed in 0ms
1513 timing idealTree:node_modules/eas-cli/node_modules/xml2js/node_modules/xmlbuilder Completed in 0ms
1514 timing idealTree:node_modules/eas-cli/node_modules/@expo/image-utils/node_modules/cross-spawn/node_modules/semver Completed in 0ms
1515 timing idealTree:buildDeps Completed in 1466ms
1516 timing idealTree:fixDepFlags Completed in 3ms
1517 timing idealTree Completed in 1482ms
1518 timing command:install Completed in 1496ms
1519 verbose stack TypeError: Invalid URL
1519 verbose stack     at new URL (node:internal/url:783:36)
1519 verbose stack     at getProxy (/Users/wliu/.nvm/versions/node/v21.2.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/agent/lib/proxy.js:81:10)
1519 verbose stack     at getAgent (/Users/wliu/.nvm/versions/node/v21.2.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/agent/lib/index.js:19:23)
1519 verbose stack     at remoteFetch (/Users/wliu/.nvm/versions/node/v21.2.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/make-fetch-happen/lib/remote.js:37:17)
1519 verbose stack     at cacheFetch (/Users/wliu/.nvm/versions/node/v21.2.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/make-fetch-happen/lib/cache/index.js:16:28)
1519 verbose stack     at async fetch (/Users/wliu/.nvm/versions/node/v21.2.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/make-fetch-happen/lib/fetch.js:98:7)
1519 verbose stack     at async RegistryFetcher.packument (/Users/wliu/.nvm/versions/node/v21.2.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/pacote/lib/registry.js:87:19)
1519 verbose stack     at async RegistryFetcher.manifest (/Users/wliu/.nvm/versions/node/v21.2.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/pacote/lib/registry.js:118:23)
1519 verbose stack     at async #nodeFromEdge (/Users/wliu/.nvm/versions/node/v21.2.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/build-ideal-tree.js:1049:19)
1519 verbose stack     at async #loadPeerSet (/Users/wliu/.nvm/versions/node/v21.2.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/build-ideal-tree.js:1310:11)
1520 verbose cwd /Users/wliu
1521 verbose Darwin 21.6.0
1522 verbose node v21.2.0
1523 verbose npm  v10.2.3
1524 error code ERR_INVALID_URL
1525 error Invalid URL
1526 verbose exit 1
```

Comment: You should really consider using a more modern version of node.

Comment: Thanks! I was changed to 16 from 21. Let me change it back to 21 and try again.

Comment: @ElvisAdomnica, thanks for the comment. I changed to v21, but same error.

Comment: Thank you Elvis! I resolved it by adding proxy settings to npm.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved by setting npm proxy:

```
➜  ~ npm config set proxy http://127.0.0.1:7890
➜  ~ npm config set https-proxy http://127.0.0.1:7890
```

I do have a proxy on my Mac, but I am not sure how it affects the npm.

Comment: hm, interesting, I guess the proxy is not applied system wide. glad you solved it!